# Pop OS dual boot with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, pop-os

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad (UEFI enabled) with Windows 10.
I just have one hard disk.
I am trying to install PopOs and have a dual boot option.

This [link](https://pop.system76.com/docs/dual-booting-windows/) from PopOs has description regarding dual-boot installation.
They have mentioned that we need to have three paritions Boot (`/boot/efi`), Root (`/`) and Swap. While installing PopOs, since I already had EFI secure partition, I selected this partition for Boot, and created new partitions for Root and Swap.

Installation was successful and when I rebooted and entered Boot menu, I can see PopOs bootloader entry has been added. But when I click on it, nothing happens. I am able to boot into my Windows though.

Answer (score 2):

Had almost the same issue - difference was I actually created a new EFI partition at the beginning of the free space; but symptoms were the same.
Here's the answer:

https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/b9o5cb/popos_dual_boot_with_windows10_not_working/ek5wuhn?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x

In short, disable secure UEFI boot in the BIOS.